# Express throw [object object] error message

Tags: node.js, express

I am confused about the Express built-in error handler.

I don't provide a custom error handler, but I do pass error via `next(err)` like the documentation says, Express just log a `[object object]` string.

Here are some simplified code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  next({})
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And when I do `curl http://localhost:3000` in the terminal, just got `[object object]`.

So my questions are:

1. **What does the `[object object]` mean?**
2. **How does the built-in error handler process the error?**
3. **Why is there no output about the error stack?**

Comment: `next(new Error('message'))`

Comment: or you can send next() without empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express uses node module [finalhandler](https://github.com/pillarjs/finalhandler#readme), that also handles the errors, when specified in `next` handler. Each time the `error` in `next` is not `null` or `undefined`, it tries to get from the `error` object `status`, `headers` and `message` itself. Related to `[object Object]` response, I guess, it's the message of the error which placed in the `html` response, and if the message is of type `Object`, it gives `[object Object]` as result when coerced to the `String`.
When getting message from the error, `finalhandler` looks for env (production or not), and based on that retrieves a message. If in development (which is default), the message will be retrieved from `error.stack', so making something like this:

```
next(new Error('Unauthorized'));
```

will give `Unauthorized` in express html error response, because in the development environment `finalhandler` will look for the `error.stack' as a message. 
In production, specifying status code, will give error messages based on the status code:

```
NODE_ENV=production node server.js

next({ status: 401 });
```

Gives:

```
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Unauthorized</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Putting an empty object literals as an error (in development):

```
next({});
```

ends up `finalhandler` receiving `undefined` from `error.stack`(when trying to extract message from the error), and then calling `error.toString()`.

> Why is there no output about the error stack?

Some helpful information can be received by setting environment variables for [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#readme). `finalhendler` also uses `degub` module. To not pollute the terminal with unnecessary information, its namespace can be used for enabling debugging:

```
DEBUG=finalhandler node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**

`[object Object]` is what `toString()` of JSON object.

Try `JSON.stringify(object)` to see what is inside.

**2, 3**

There is no built-in error handler in express.

If you read through [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

You'll see they have define error-handling middleware which have four arguments after all the `app.use`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  next({}) // try change to next(new Error('Something wrong')) and see the log
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: As far as I know, Express documentation says `Express comes with a built-in error handler`, just at the bottom of the doc you attached...